# RegEx is not working for Some conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate Name fields in my project and have different validation conditions for it.

Starting Name:

1. Min. length of 2 chars.
2. Can be alphabetic chars, blanks and hyphens.
3. The 1st char must be alphabetic.
4. Blanks & Hyphens must not be adjacent

My Regex:-

```
function fname(value){
var fn = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]*[ -]{0,1}[a-zA-Z])+([ -]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)*");
if(fn.test(value)){
          return true;  
         }
         else{          
            return false;
         }
}
```

Last Name:

1. Can be alphabetic chars, blanks, hyphens and apostrophes.
2. 1st char must be alphabetic.
3. Blanks, hyphens and apostrophes must not be adjacent.
4. 1 char is acceptable only if that char is O

My Regex:

```
function fname(value){
    var ln = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]|([ '][a-zA-Z])|([-][a-zA-Z])){1,}|[O]{1})");
    if(ln.test(value)){
              return true;  
             }
             else{          
                return false;
             }
    }
```

Both these regex are failing as they are accepting:

1. Alphanumeric characters are getting acceptable which shouldn't be.
2. space, hyphen adjacent (in case of starting name) and space, hyphen and apostrophes adjacent (in case of last name) at any position in string.

Comment: The `{1}` is redundant and `{0, 1}` is the same as `?`.

Comment: Also just `return ln.test(value);`

Comment: To make your question easier for other to answer, it might have been better is you also supplied examples, for ones that pass, and ones you want to fail.  Also a working Snippet wouldn't harm.

Comment: A good online tool is here: https://regexr.com You can verify tweaks quickly and easily.

Comment: Is `a-` valid or not?

Comment: well you do not test for a full string....

Comment: Thanks All for early reply, will correct the thing for this as well as from next time.

Comment: My expectation for FName example:-
aa, a bc, a-b c, etc....

Failure:-
-a, - abc, ab -c/ab- c, ab -/abc- , alphanumeric, etc...

@ibrahimmahrir, a- is valid

Comment: Same for Last Name only apostrophe will be added condition with hyphen and blank space. rest will be the same as i given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can be done with a single regex, the easiest solution is to just separate the tests:

```
function is_valid_first_name(str) {
    return (
        str.length >= 2 &&
        /^[a-zA-Z \-]*$/.test(str) &&
        /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(str) &&
        !/[ \-]{2}/.test(str)
    );
}

function is_valid_last_name(str) {
    return (
        /^[a-zA-Z \-']*$/.test(str) &&
        /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(str) &&
        !/[ \-']{2}/.test(str) &&
        (str.length > 1 || str === 'O')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, both functions have the same name. Maybe that's just a typo.

In any case, I think this does what you want for the first name. It doesn't allow a trailing space or hyphen, but that seems to be implied.

```js
const re_fname = /^[a-zA-Z](?:[- ]?|(?:[a-zA-Z][- ]?)+)$/;

function fname(value){
  const res = re_fname.test(value);
  console.log("%s: %s", res ? "PASS" : "FAIL", value);
  return res;
}

fname("foo-bar");
fname("foobar");
fname("f-");
fname("f--");
fname("foo-bar-");
fname("foo-bar--");
fname("-foo-bar");
fname("foo--bar");
fname("foo bar");
fname("foo  bar");
fname("foo- bar");
```

And the last name, which is nearly identical, only adding the apostrophe to the set, and allowing for a single `O` match.

```js
const re_lname = /^(?:O|(?:[' -]?|[a-zA-Z](?:[' -]?[a-zA-Z])+)[' -]?)$/;
  
function lname(value){
  const res = re_lname.test(value);
  console.log("%s: %s", res ? "PASS" : "FAIL", value);
  return res;
}

lname("O");
lname("X");
lname("foobar");
lname("foo-bar");
lname("foo-bar-");
lname("foo-bar-'");
lname("foo-bar'");
lname("-foo-bar");
lname("foo--bar");
lname("foo bar");
lname("foo  bar");
lname("foo- bar");
lname("foo'bar");
lname("foo' bar");
lname("foo'- bar");
lname("foo-'bar");
```

Comment: Why does `foo-bar-` fail? It doesn't break one of the rules.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: I noted the reason in my answer. *"It doesn't allow a trailing space or hyphen, but that seems to be implied."*

Comment: It says "1 char is acceptable only if that char is O", not "1st char".

Comment: @melpomene: Thanks, I misread that as the first character. I'll update.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: To be specific, his attempted regex tries to require a trailing alphabetical character.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong as `a-` is a valid first name. [**Proof**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242474/regex-is-not-working-for-some-conditions?noredirect=1#comment79452247_46242474).

Comment: lol, calm down @ibrahimmahrir. It was reasonable given that that's how the original regex reads.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I see you aren't specifying start and end of string boundaries in your regexps so any string **conatining** a matching substring will validate:

```
> "Hello".match(/[a-z]+/)
[ 'ello', index: 1, input: 'Hello' ]
> "Hello".match(/^[a-z]+$/)
null
```

Another ugly thing I see are unescaped hyphens in character classes (`[ -]`). **Even in this case is valid** (it will work as you expect) but is ugly because it has special meaning in character classes (depending on context) so minimal and apparently inoffensive changes may break things that were already working:

```
> "-".match(/[abc-]/);
[ '-', index: 0, input: '-' ]
> "-".match(/[abc-j]/);
null
```

Answering your question: Ignoring 4th rule it's pretty easy:

```
> "hello-world as foo".match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/)
[ 'hello-world as foo', index: 0, input: 'hello-world as foo' ]
```

- First character class (`[a-zA-Z]`) ensures 2nd rule and is compatible with rules n. 1 and 3 too.
- The second character class (`[a-zA-Z\s\-]`) matches any valid character according rule n. 2.
- Following quantifier (`+`) ensures one or more occurrences which, plus the initial character matched by initial character class sums 2 or more characters (so fits rule n. 1).
- Finally, starting and ending `^` and `$` boundaries ensures, that matching starts from the really beginning of the string and ends at its end so, as I explained earlier, matching substrings aren't enough to validate if invalid characters are present.

4th rule is a bit more tricky. I think it can be approached by *lookbehind* and *lookahead* expressions, but they are not available on all regex engines (even in javascript I think they aren't at least in some ancient versions).

...and, even if available, they are always suboptimal (from the regex engine implementation point of view).

On the other hand, you could rely on grouping instead of character classes combining groups with spaces and groups with hyphens, but that will darken your final expression apart of making it harder to build, understand an test. So, in my opinion it isn't a good solution too.

**BUT** if you are not forced to use single regular expression it's pretty easy to check apart by an ad hoc expression.

```
function fname(value){
    return !!( // <- (optional) Boolean cast for more consistent return type.
        value.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/)
        && ! value.match(/\s-|-\s/)
    );
}

console.log (fname("hello-world as foo")); // true
console.log (fname("hello- world as foo")); // false
console.log (fname("hello -world as foo")); // false
console.log (fname("-hello-world as foo")); // false (null without "!!" cast).
console.log (fname(" hello-world as foo")); // false (null without "!!" cast).
```

...as a final note, I used "`\s`" character class instead of "" for spaces. This matches other *spacing* characters too (like tabs and, in some conditions, line breaks, etc...) if you don't want to accept those characters, replace all "`\s`" occurrence by simple spaces.

I preferred to use "`\s`" in the sake of readability (and because in most cases I like it much more if other spacings are acceptable, but I think in this case it's not).

> Last name rules are pretty much the same so required changes are trivial following the same reasoning.